# How to display superscript dynamic values in dynamically created table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    var a = new Array();
    var table1 = document.createElement('table');
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        j = i.toString();
        a = 2+j.sup();
    }

    for(tableIndex=0;tableIndex<10;tableIndex++)
    {
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(a[tableIndex]);                         
        td1.appendChild(text1);                             
        tr.appendChild(td1);                                
        td1.style.borderStyle = "solid";
        td1.style.padding = "10px";
    }
    table1.appendChild(tr);
</script>
```

In this script, I have created dynamic table and i want value inside row to be superscript of 2.But it is not getting displayed properly,it shows something like "2 sup 0 sup close" tags.

Comment: length is not defined, also you want a[i]

Comment: length is variable, it can have any value

Answer (score 0):

As [explained by the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/sup), the `sup` function is very deprecated. I suggest you wrap your number in a `<span></span>`, add a sup class and use css to style it.